# How do we extract month from a column with timestamp values using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting and I am facing trouble on a particular task.

I have a csv file with 30 columns and over 1000 rows. I want to extract the month from a particular column that has values given in timestamps and store it to another file.

The date is given in "*yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss*" format

```
        "date"
    2016-11-30 23:00:00
    2016-07-23 22:30:00
    2016-03-21 23:00:00
```

I want to print the months in each line in a different file, like this:

```
11

07

03
```

Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: There is a large number of near-duplicate questions on this site already. You are expected to demonstrate some effort before asking, at least to show what you have googled and how you were unable to use the results you found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cut command twice

Let's say the data file is so:

```
a date,Z
"aa",2016-11-30 23:00:00,"x"
"bb",2016-07-23 22:30:00,"y"
"cc",2016-03-21 23:00:00,"z"
```

We can first read the date column and then cut it again by -

```
cut -f 2 -d ',' dtlst.csv | cut -f 2 -d '-'|sed 1d
```

The first `cut` reads the 2nd field , ie, `date` column.The `cut` after pipe `|` again delimits by `-` and reads the 2nd column . Finally `sed` deletes 1 header row .
Tested on Ubuntu20.04

Output:

```
11
07
03
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Sed

```sh
sed -E '1d;s/.*-([0-9]{2})-.*/\1/' input_file
```

- the `-E` option is to use [EREs instead of BREs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html), so to use `(`, `)`, `{`, and `}` instead of `\(`, `\)`, `\{`, and `\}`
- `1d` deletes (in other word *does not print*) the first line
- `s/.*-([0-9]{2})-.*/\1/'` captures between `(` and `)` the two (`{2}`) digits (`[0-9]`) making up the month and also matches the two `-` on each side, plus whatever (`.*`) comes before and after, and substitutes everything with what was captured, `\1`.

Given the specificity of the use case, you can even go simpler:

```sh
sed -E '1d;s/.*-([^-]+)-.*/\1/' input_file
```

where the number is not matched as a sequence of two digits, but as a squence of one or more, `+`, non-dashes, `[^-]`.

Comment: This may be broken if the csv file has multi-column as author mentioned above and unfortunately there is another date-format column. I think we should extract this "date" column and pass to this solution of @Enrico.

Comment: @LuanPhan, yeah, you're right, but the OP didn't give any example of the original file. Plus, giving just that column, leads me to think that he knows how to extract that column, so that it can pass _it_ to my script. However, I've marked the question as _need more info_ just for this reason.